# Get selected item in datasheet

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I've created Microsoft access database. The database is a few tables with forms to enter data into.
The forms are split data forms with only a header for buttons and a data sheet for the data entry, but I was wondering if there was a way with VBA to get the selected row in the data sheet.

Basically what I'm wanting to do is allow the users to select the item in the data sheet and clicking a button to go to that item in a different form.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are plenty of methods. But you should browse for a guide/tutorial like "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or similar.

Comment: Explore the DoCmd.OpenForm method.

Comment: Opening another form is easy, I'm just trying to get the ID of the selected cell in a datasheet.

Comment: Try

`Me.CurrentRecord`

or

`Me.ActiveControl.Value`

Answer (score 2):

Selecting records in the datasheet section of a Split form will automatically navigate to the appropriate record in the form's Record Source, therefore, referencing any field on the form will automatically return the value corresponding to the selected record.